# An effective way using Disqus API

Tags: ios, disqus

Background info:

- iOS app on iOS 7.0+
- Moqod iOS library ( https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios )
- App would load comment for any time user view the wordpress post detail.

Case Description :

This question is mainly raised by the 1000 requests limit per hour from Disqus API. For my app, I load the comments when user views a post detail. If 1000 is the limit, it will be reached if there are more than 1000 people view post detail within a hour. I believe it is really easy to reach. Try to think about if there is 1 000 000 users are using my app. if 1% of the pool view posts within an hour. It will be broken.
I haven't count it takes extra call to obtain the thread ID which used on posting message and the number of posting comment.

Question :

How do people usually design an iOS app would satisfy the above case ??

Or Do I have an incorrect approach of using the Disqus API ??

Please kindly help.
Thanks